# How to combine template and inheritance

Tags: c++

I have multiple factories, each is responsible for creating instances of an inheritance tree.  For example (syntax or semantics maybe incorrect),

```
struct InterfaceA {};  struct ImplA1 : InterfaceA {}; ... 
struct FactoryA { vector<InterfaceA*> create(); }    
... // (repeat for B, C, etc)
```

`foo` is template class

```
template<ATy, BTy, ..>
struct foo {
     // default behavior - no functionality
};
```

`foo` is specialized for some combination of subclasses of InterfaceA, InterfaceB, and ...

```
template<>
struct foo<ImplA1, ImplB2, ..> {
     void feature1();
     void feature2();
};
```

Is it possible to combine the inheritance hierarchies with the template class?  i.e.

```
void bar(vector<InterfaceA*> vecA, vector<InterfaceB*> vecB, ..) {
    foo< /* what to put in here */ >(vecA.front(), vecB.front(), ...) f;
    f.feature1();  // if specialization not there, complain
}
```

I can use [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (CRTP) for one tree.  Not sure how to get it work with multi trees.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve. The static types of `vecA.front()` and `vecB.front()` are clearly known. And if you need to instantiate a `template` based on their *dynamic* type – well, you can't do that…

Comment: vecA.front() is InterfaceA*?

Comment: @CandyChiu: Yes, `vecA.front()` returns an item of type `InterfaceA*`. It can point to an `ImplA1`, `ImplA2` or any other derived class of `InterfaceA`.

Comment: Yes, so in template resolution, it won't select the specialized.

Answer (score 1):

Seems what you want is:

```
void bar(vector<InterfaceA*> vecA, vector<InterfaceB*> vecB) {
    // If InterfaceA == ImplA1 && InterfaceB == ImplB2 then:
    foo<ImplA1, ImplB2> f(*dynamic_cast<const ImplA1*>(vecA.front()), *dynamic_cast<const ImplB2*>(vecB.front()));
    // ...
    f.feature1();  // if specialization not there, complain
}
```

which is not possibly, because the template instantiation is a compile-time thing and you want to make a decision on a dynamic run time type. (Btw. Even above only works if you give `InterfaceA|B` a virtual d'tor.)

So from your comment `// if spec not there, complain` I can state this:

- You cannot complain at compile time, because the decision to make is based on run time information
- You could write a runtime dispatcher that selects the correct template instantiation (or fails with e.g. an exception) at run time: How to do that is another story, possibly best asked over at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).